# Sphinx partial word search, version 2.2.4

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm using Sphinx to provide a search webpage to a huge set of data, recently I upgraded Sphinx from v2.1.8 to v2.2.4

I had some troubles in config file, one of them is that 'enable_star' option has been removed, which affected the expected results in my search page, so if search for 'rea' it will not return 'real madrid' until I complete typing 'real', the same issue at words ends 'madrid'.

The expected results if I searched for 'mad' :

- Real Madrid
- Atlatico Madrid
- Mad-Croc
- Madila
- mad bla

In my case I get 'Mad-Croc' and 'mad bla'.

Here is a part of my config file :

```
docinfo = extern
mlock = 0
morphology = stem_en
min_word_len = 1
expand_keywords = 1
dict = keywords
```

PHP Code :

```
$_sphinx = new SphinxClient();

$_sphinx->SetServer('............', '....');

$_sphinx->SetMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_ANY);
$_sphinx->SetFieldWeights(array('auther_name' => 50));
$_sphinx->SetArrayResult(true);
$_sphinx->SetSortMode(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED2, 'cat_priority DESC, @weight DESC');

//////////////////
$_result = $_sphinx->Query($searchTerm . '*');
```

could any body look for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont seem to have `min_prefix_len` setup on your index, suggest you add it.

Although not sure how your index would ever of worked, as `min_prefix_len`, would be required for `enable_star=0` to have an effect.

That should allow `expand_keywords` to work its magic. At which poing suggest removing the * from the end of the query. Which would only affect the last word entered anyway, and * should autotmatically by added by `expand_keywords` setting anyway.

Comment: Yes, it worked, but I got a warning :

dict=keywords and prefixes and morphology enabled, forcing index_exact_words=1